# ClickHouse insert nested data

Tags: ruby, clickhouse

How I can insert to ClickHouse data below?

```
tests => [{"test_id"=>1099803, "test_number"=>"35545585544", "test_number_2"=>"123456", "test_source"=>nil}, "test_id"=>1099804, "test_number"=>"1313113", "test_number_2"=>"654321", "test_source"=>nil}, {...}]
```

Comment: Step 1 is usually "read some documentation and look for examples".

Answer (score 1):

ClickHouse offers few approaches that can be helpful in your case:

- Store information as JSON. It's slower to query and potentially taking larger disk footprint, it's also less structured but giving you full freedom of expression. Column data type will be [string](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/data-types/string/), you can use [JSONExtract*](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/json-functions/#jsonextractuintjson-indices-or-keys) to access the data.
- Use [nested data format](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/data-types/nested-data-structures/nested/#nestedname1-type1-name2-type2).